# SQL Server 2012 Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Tags: sql

I'm still learning SQL so this is really basic. Im trying to get the Project Inserts to go into the project table, but Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. keeps on coming up can someone point out whats wrong

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT (
ASN_NUM         CHAR (2)        NOT NULL        CHECK (ASN_NUM IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20')),
ASN_DATE        VARCHAR (9)     NOT NULL,
ASN_PRO_NUM CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (ASN_PRO_NUM IN ('123','124','125','126','127','128')) REFERENCES PROJECT (PRO_NUM),
ASN_EMP_NUM     CHAR (1)        NOT NULL        CHECK (ASN_EMP_NUM IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMP_NUM),
ASN_JOB_CODE    CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (ASN_JOB_CODE IN ('ACT','DAN','DSD','DSS','NAD','NIN','SAN','SMO')) REFERENCES JOB (JOB_CODE),
ASN_HOURS       DECIMAL (4,2)       DEFAULT 0,
ASN_CHG_HR      MONEY           DEFAULT 0,
ASN_CHARGE      MONEY           DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (ASN_NUM)
)
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('1','20-Jun-99','127','3','DSD','2.60',175.00,435.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('2','20-Jun-99','123','6','SMO','1.80',85.00,53.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('3','20-Jun-99','123','6','SAN','2.00',145.00,290.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('4','20-Jun-99','126','2','NAD','3.70',120.00,444.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('5','20-Jun-99','128','7','DSS','3.20',79.50,254.40);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('6','20-Jun-99','127','2','DSD','2.90',175.00,507.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('7','20-Jun-99','123','7','DSD','2.90',175.00,507.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('8','20-Jun-99','125','5','NAD','1.50',120.00,180.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('9','20-Jun-99','124','3','DSD','2.30',175.00,402.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('10','20-Jun-99','127','5','NAD','4.30',120.00,516.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('11','20-Jun-99','123','3','DSD','3.80',175.00,665.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('12','21-Jun-99','126','7','DAN','1.50',95.00,142.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('13','21-Jun-99','127','6','SAN','5.00',145.00,725.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('14','21-Jun-99','125','3','DSD','2.90',175.00,507.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('15','21-Jun-99','123','6','SMO','3.80',85.00,323.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('16','21-Jun-99','128','5','NAD','4.10',120.00,492.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('17','21-Jun-99','123','7','DAN','6.30',95.00,598.50);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('18','21-Jun-99','125','2','NAD','11.20',120.00,1,344.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('19','21-Jun-99','125','3','DSD','2.80',175.00,490.00);
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES ('20','01-Feb-99','123','1','SMO','2.00',85.00,170.00);

CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
CLI_NUM     CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (CLI_NUM IN ('112','114','115','118','122','123')),
CLI_LNAME   VARCHAR (20)        NOT NULL,
CLI_FNAME   VARCHAR (20)        NOT NULL,
CLI_MINI    VARCHAR (10),
CLI_ADD     VARCHAR (30)        NOT NULL,
CLI_CITY    VARCHAR (12)        NOT NULL,
CLI_STATE   CHAR (2)        NOT NULL,
CLI_ZIP     CHAR (5)        NOT NULL,
CLI_AREA    CHAR (3)        NOT NULL,
CLI_PHONE   CHAR (8)        NOT NULL        CHECK (CLI_PHONE LIKE ('[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
PRIMARY KEY (CLI_NUM)
)

INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('112','Chasteen','Anne','R','1234 Rose Lane','Murfreesboro','TN','37130','615','123-2345');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('114','Williamson','Kirby','T','2345 Grove Street','Nashville','TN','32001','615','234-5678');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('115','Quahtoty','hrman','','3456 Waterford Rd.','Nashville','TN','32008','615','239-9876');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('118','Smith','Mary','M','4567 Oleander Blvd.','Owensboro','KY','38345','652','456-6543');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('122','Taylor','Christopher','F','5678 Treeline Rd.','Murfreesboro','TN','37130','615','238-3344');
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('123','Trevors','Anne','K','6789 Sweetwater Dr.','Louisville','KY','39932','654','654-9001');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EMP_NUM     CHAR (1)        NOT NULL        CHECK (EMP_NUM IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')),
EMP_LNAME   VARCHAR (20)        NOT NULL,
EMP_FNAME   VARCHAR (15)        NOT NULL,
EMP_MINI    VARCHAR (10),
EMP_DOB     VARCHAR (35)        NOT NULL,
EMP_VETERAN VARCHAR (3)     NOT NULL        CHECK (EMP_VETERAN IN ('YES','NO')),
PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NUM)
)

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('1','Dempsey','John','R','Wednesday, December 02, 1970','No');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('2','Smithson','Susan','B','Saturday, April 11, 1964','Yes');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('3','Smith','James','D','Sunday, September 23, 1973','No');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('4','McDermott','Anne','W','Friday, November 28, 1975','No');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('5','Cheng','George','','Friday, July 09, 1971','Yes');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('6','Jackson','Marie','J','Saturday, October 16, 1971','No');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('7','Hernandez','Carlos','M','Friday, April 23, 1965','No');

CREATE TABLE JOB (
JOB_CODE        CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (JOB_CODE IN ('ACT','DAN','DSD','DSS','NAD','NIN','SAN','SMO')),
JOB_DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR (45)        NOT NULL,
JOB_CHG_HOUR        MONEY           DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (JOB_CODE)
)

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('ACT','Accountant',75.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('DAN','Data Analyst',95.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('DSD','Database Systems Designer',175.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('DSS','Decision Support Systems Specialist',79.50);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('NAD','Network Administrator',120.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('NIN','Network Installer',110.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('SAN','Systems Analyst',145.00);
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES ('SMO','Statistical Modeler',85.00);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
PRO_NUM         CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (PRO_NUM IN ('123','124','125','126','127','128')),
PRO_NAME        VARCHAR (20)        NOT NULL,
PRO_CLI_NUM     CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (PRO_CLI_NUM IN ('118','122','114','112','118','114')) REFERENCES CLIENT (CLI_NUM),
PRO_COST        MONEY           DEFAULT 0,
PRO_OPEN_DATE       VARCHAR (30)        NOT NULL,
PRO_MANAGER     CHAR (1)        NOT NULL,
PRO_COORDINATOR     CHAR (1)        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PRO_NUM)
)

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('123','Rock Veil','118',2,707.00,'Monday, May 12, 1997','2','5');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('124','Willow Branch','122',785,000.00,'Monday, August 24, 1998','7','3');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('125','Tin Roof','114',4,557,500.00,'Tuesday, May 12, 1998','6','5');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('126','Freeze','112',1,080,000.00,'Tuesday, March 30, 1999','5','2');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('127','Rumble Seat','118',3,010,000.00,'Thursday, June 11, 1998','2','6');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES ('128','Fancy Flight','114',6,805,000.00,'Tuesday, June 22, 1999','5','7');

CREATE TABLE SKILL (
SKILL_EMP_NUM       CHAR (1)        NOT NULL        CHECK (SKILL_EMP_NUM IN ('2','2','3','5','6','6','7','7','7')) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMP_NUM),
SKILL_JOB_CODE      CHAR (3)        NOT NULL        CHECK (SKILL_JOB_CODE IN ('DSD','NAD','DSD','NAD','SAN','SMO','DAN','DSD','DSS')) REFERENCES JOB (JOB_CODE),
SKILL_DATE      VARCHAR (35)        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SKILL_EMP_NUM, SKILL_JOB_CODE)
)       

INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('2','DSD','Monday, November 09, 1998');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('2','NAD','Friday, February 14, 1997');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('3','DSD','Thursday, April 11, 1996');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('5','NAD','Tuesday, December 05, 1995');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('6','SAN','Monday, July 23, 1990');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('6','SMO','Wednesday, September 02, 1992');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('7','DAN','Friday, November 28, 1997');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('7','DSD','Tuesday, June 22, 1999');
INSERT INTO SKILL VALUES ('7','DSS','Monday, May 17, 1993');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little long for a comment.

When using `insert`, you should always be in the habit of including all the column names.  So your first insert should look like:

```
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT(ASN_NUM, ASN_DATE, ASN_PRO_NUM, ASN_EMP_NUM, ASN_JOB_CODE, ASN_HOURS, ASN_CHG_HR, ASN_CHARGE)
    VALUES ('1','20-Jun-99','127','3','DSD','2.60',175.00,435.00);
```

This won't necessarily fix the problem, but it will make it easier to debug.

To find the problem, run the code one table at a time to isolate the issue.